# MYSQL error and join statements

Tags: mysql, join

I'm using the following MYSQL statement but im getting the error: 'ErrorUnknown column 'property.id' in 'on clause'

i've searched around and I think it's something to do with the JOIN and Mysql 5? this makes sense as the code used to work so a mysql update might have broken it

How can i change my statement to stop the error happening?

```
SELECT property.id, 
       Concat(IF (name = '', '', Concat(name, '<br />')), 
       IF (address = '', '', Concat(address, '<br />')), IF (city = '', '', 
                                                         Concat(city, '<br />')) 
       , IF ( 
       postcode = '', '', Concat(postcode, ', ')), property_region.region) AS 
       name, 
       property_type.type, 
       short_description, 
       property_tenure.tenure, 
       Format(sell_price, 0)                                               AS 
       sell_price, 
       Format(rent_price, 0)                                               AS 
       rent_price, 
       area, 
       CASE property.tenure 
         WHEN 1 THEN '' 
         WHEN 2 THEN 'display:none' 
         WHEN 3 THEN '' 
       end                                                                 AS 
       sell_display, 
       CASE property.tenure 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'display:none' 
         WHEN 2 THEN '' 
         WHEN 3 THEN '' 
       end                                                                 AS 
       rent_display, 
       IF (thumb_image_name = '', 'no_image.gif', thumb_image_name)        AS 
       thumb_image_name, 
       IF (bookmarks.property_id, 'checked=\"checked\"', '')               AS 
       bookmark_checked 
FROM   property, 
       property_tenure, 
       property_region, 
       property_type 
       LEFT JOIN bookmarks 
              ON property.id = bookmarks.property_id 
                 AND bookmarks.user_id = $user_id 
WHERE  property.featured = 1 
       AND property.active = 1 
       AND property.region = property_region.id 
       AND property.tenure = property_tenure.id 
       AND property.type = property_type.id 
ORDER  BY timestamp
```

Comment: Does your `property` table have an `id` column?

Comment: yep there is an id column in the property table

Comment: i found this which might help but i don't understand it http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/having-unknown-column-in-on-clause-error-323495.html

Comment: This link suggests you to use JOINs instead of list of tables in FROM clause.

Comment: I fixed it! I just need to put () around the FROM e.g. FROM   (property, 
       property_tenure, 
       property_region, 
       property_type) 
       LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

...try this one -

```
...
FROM property p
  JOIN property_tenure pt
    ON pt.id = p.tenure
  JOIN property_region pr
    ON pr.id = p.region
  JOIN property_type ptype
    ON ptype.id = p.type
  LEFT JOIN bookmarks b
    ON p.id = b.property_id AND b.user_id = $user_id 
WHERE
  property.featured = 1 AND property.active = 1
...
```